# Joi Conditional Validation: Error When Validating 'platformConfig.platformApiKey' Based on 'platform

Tags: javascript, joi

I'm using joi for schema validation.

I need to validate the following data

```
"body": { 
    "event": "someEvent",
    "frequency": "someFrequency",
    "ApiToken": "samsaraApiToken",
    "TelematicsTypes": "someTele",
    "platform": "Uber | DIDI | SinDelantal",
    "platformConfig": {
      "platformApiKey": "someApiKey"
      "platformUser": "someUser",
      "platformPassword": "somePass"
    }
```

I need to make the following validations:

1. If the platform is Uber or DIDI then platformApiKey is required, user and password are optional
2. If the platform is SinDelantal, then user and password are required, and platformApiKey is optional.

this is my joi file

```
platform: joi.string().valid('Uber', 'DIDI', 'SinDelantal').required(),
      platformConfig: joi.object({

        platformApiKey: joi.alternatives().conditional('platform', {
          is: joi.valid('Uber', 'DIDI'),
          then: joi.string().required(),
        })
        .conditional('platform', {
          is: joi.not(joi.valid('Uber', 'DIDI')),
          then: joi.string().allow('').optional(),
        }),

        platformUser: joi.alternatives().conditional('platform', {
          is: 'SinDelantal',
          then: joi.string().required(),
        })
        .conditional('platform', {
          is: joi.not(joi.valid('')),
          then: joi.string().allow('').optional(),
        }),

        platformPassword: joi.alternatives().conditional('platform', {
          is: 'SinDelantal',
          then: joi.string().required(),
        })
        .conditional('platform', {
          is: joi.not(joi.valid('sinDelantal')),
          then: joi.string().allow('').optional(),
        }),
      }).required(),
    });
```

But the problems I have is

1. When the platform is Kronh then this description shows up
   description: '"platformConfig.platformApiKey" is not allowed to be empty',

even though I said it was optional and blank is allowed
2) When the platform is any platform and I leave blank the values, the tests pass.

I read the documentation, and I'm seeking help to see what I'm I missing

Answer (score 0):

I try to use only one `alternatives().conditional()` for each key, and it seems to work. Also, I think the better way to reference platform is `...platform`.

Normally, you don't need to use nested `Joi.object()`

Try this

```js
const body = {
  platform: "Uber",
  platformConfig: {
    platformApiKey: "someApiKey",
    platformUser: "",
    platformPassword: undefined,
  },
};

const schema = Joi.object({
  platform: Joi.string().valid("Uber", "DIDI", "SinDelantal").required(),
  platformConfig: {
    platformApiKey: Joi.alternatives().conditional("...platform", {
      is: Joi.string().equal("Uber", "DIDI"),
      then: Joi.string().required(),
      otherwise: Joi.any().optional(),
    }),
    platformUser: Joi.alternatives().conditional("...platform", {
      is: Joi.string().equal("SinDelantal"),
      then: Joi.string().required(),
      otherwise: Joi.any().optional(),
    }),
    platformPassword: Joi.alternatives().conditional("...platform", {
      is: Joi.string().equal("SinDelantal"),
      then: Joi.string().required(),
      otherwise: Joi.any().optional(),
    }),
  },
});
```

Comment: it worked!! thabk you very much!! can you explain this, please? why "...platform", instead of "platform"

Comment: `platform` is a reference to a key. We should use just `platform` if it was at the same nested level as `platformApiKey`. But here, it's on a parent level. You can consider `...` as a path to reach `platform`. You can find different path models [here](https://joi.dev/api/#refkey-options)